# Do action after Cache expires on Symfony5

Tags: symfony, events, caching, filesystems, listener

all is in the title. Is there a Listener which help to do some actions when cache expires. I used **FilesystemAdapter** to create a cache item.
When you made it, there is a "expiresAfter" method which define when, that cache item will expires. So, is there a way to listen this action ?

Thanks.

Here a sample code for how to create a cache item :

```
public function cacheFile(string $key, string $filename, string $chunkName, int $uid)
    {
        $cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
        $chunk = $cache->getItem($key .".". $uid);

        if ($chunk->isHit()) {
            $elements = $chunk->get();
            $elements[$filename][] = ["chunkName" => $chunkName];
        }
        else $elements[$filename][] = ["chunkName" => $chunkName];
        $chunk->set(array_unique($elements, SORT_REGULAR));
        $chunk->expiresAfter( (int) $this->bag->get("cacheDocTtl"));
        $cache->save($chunk);
    }
```

Comment: There is no built-in event to handle such things but depending on your context and your problem, we could maybe find a solution. Could you give more details please ?

Comment: Cache expiring is not an event. Further calls to try to retrieve the cache item won't hit the cache, that's all.

Comment: Thanks @FlorianHermann. What I'm trying is, receiving some files from a client and stock them on a temporary folder. Then I wait another request from the client to confirm if I could link them to database.
If front never call the second request, I need to delete these files. I don't know if it's clear.

Comment: Okay @yivi. Another solution is to check cache each time, to do what I want. But it looks too weird

Comment: That's exactly what `isHit()` does. Check if the cache item exists and is not expired. That's the way you normally work with cache.

Comment: @yivi yes of. But what I'm saying in my case, I'll use each in each request and it's not a nice behaviour

Comment: That's exactly the way cache is supposed to used. It seems you want to reinvent cache, but maybe you do not fully understand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @yivi maybe. Ok thanks